# How to show custom rss feeds in administration panel?

Tags: wordpress, feed

I want to create new area in WordPress administration with a button in the menu area. And to have there news feeds in widgets.

Or maybe create new widgets in the dashboard with custom rss feeds, like a "wordpress.org news" and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dashboard widgets <kbd>WordPress Blog</kbd> and <kbd>Other WordPress News</kbd> can be configured to show your selected feeds:

[image]

## ⬇

[image]

To create your own widgets, [check this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wp_add_dashboard_widget).

Answer (score 0):

So let’s start to adding custom news feed your WordPress theme admin dashboard. Adding this snippet to the functions.php of your WordPress theme will let you replace the existing RSS feed widget with another RSS feed.

```
function esoft_dashboard_news_feed() {
     global $wp_meta_boxes;
     unset(
          $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_plugins'],
          $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_secondary'],
          $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_primary']
     );
     wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'dashboard_custom_feed', 'YOUR_FEED_NAME' , 'dashboard_custom_feed_output' ); 
}

function dashboard_custom_feed_output() {
     echo '<div class="rss-widget">';
     wp_widget_rss_output(array(
          'url' => 'http://www.e2soft.com/blog/feed/',
          'title' => 'YOUR_FEED_TITLE',
          'items' => 3,
          'show_summary' => 1,
          'show_author' => 0,
          'show_date' => 1
     ));
     echo '</div>';
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'esoft_dashboard_news_feed');
```

Just paste this on your theme functions.php file and replace “YOUR_FEED_NAME” by your news feed name, “http://www.e2soft.com/blog/feed/” by your feed URL, “YOUR_FEED_TITLE” by your feed title, input display item no, 0 or 1 for show date & author. That’s all for adding custom news feed you your WordPress theme admin dashboard.

Please visit for details [How to Add News Feed WordPress Admin Dashboard](http://www.e2soft.com/blog/how-to-add-news-feed-wordpress-admin-dashboard/)

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a plugin for root level user. You can download & use the plugin for easy use. It has also good settings panel for configure for your News Feed WordPress to Admin Dashboard [Download Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-admin-dashboard-news-feed/)